# Why does Horizontalgauge output flicker when i sliding the marker?

Tags: slider

The simplest HorizontalGauge[] as following:

```
HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[x], {0, 100}]
```

when i dragged the triangle marker along the axis, the axis kept flicker until i released it, but if i used Slider[] instead as following:

```
Slider[Dynamic[k], {0, 100}]
```

the Slider never flicker, so what's the problem with HorzontalGauge[]?

Comment: probably version/os related. Both work without flicker in version 11.3.0 (Windows 10 - 64 bit)

Comment: Doesn't flicker for me, either. (V12.1.1, Mac)